# Client server communication trouble

Tags: java, client-server

I am having trouble bouncing object between the client and the server.

**Create an object. Update some fields. Send to Server. (this part works)**

```
SomeObject thisObject = new SomeObject();
thisObject.setSomeValue(13);          // update object to be sent

PrintStream toServer = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(toServer);

oos.writeObject(thisObject);
oos.close();

toServer.println(oos);               // send object to server
toServer.flush();
```

**Right after this, server further updates some value and sets it to 1919;**

```
ObjectInputStream objFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
        sock.getInputStream()));

Served thisObject = (Served) objFromClient.readObject();
thisObject.setSomeValue(1919);
```

**Server then sends the object back to client**

```
toClient = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(toClient);

oos.writeObject(thisObject);

oos.close();
objFromClient.close();
sock.close();
```

But when the time comes to pick up the object back on the client side .. programs fails with Socket Closed exception

```
ObjectInputStream objFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()));      //java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed

thisObject = (Served) objFromServer.readObject();
....
```

Please help me understand the issue

Comment: Can you please show the code that's creating the `Socket`?

Comment: It is as simple as `Socket sock = new Socket(serverName, SERVER_PORT);`

Comment: This is probably not the problem, but still:  why do you have both `oos.writeObject(thisObject);
oos.close();`
and
`toServer.println(oos);
toServer.flush();` in the first step?  Wouldn't you just need the first pair of lines?  Can `PrintStream.println()` even accept an `ObjectOutputStream` as a parameter and does it make any sense?

Comment: Ultimately i am sending an object back and forth. Something like this won't apply `serverResponse = fromServer.readLine();` i don' think. Program contains no syntax issues things compile fine

Comment: Is the client reusing the same `sock`? Closing a stream from a `Socket` will close the socket.

Comment: Right, what I mean is that doesn't the `oos.writeObject(thisObject)` piece already accomplish the sending of the object to the server?

Comment: Well, server waits for a connection to happen on `sock = servsock.accept();` it's listen port and since that moment handles `sock` as its own local variable. Commenting `sock.close()` in server code does not address the issue.

Comment: @sparc_spread You are correct. `println and flush()` code was not needed. This, however is not an issue

Comment: OK, we can rule out those lines.  Now I think what @Paul is talking about is `sock` on the client side.  If the `sock` variable is the same one being used by both `oos` and `objFromServer`, then it's possible that the `oos.close()` is closing `sock`.  Try moving the `oos.close()` to after the `thisObject = ` piece and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're using the same `Socket` to both send and receive from the client. When you close the `ObjectOutputStream` on the client, this closes the underlying `OutputStream`, which closes `sock`. Then, when you try to reuse it below, it's been closed and throws an exception.

Instead, wait for the transaction to finish before closing your resources in the client code (which should be done in a `finally` block by the way). Or, if waiting is problematic, use a new `Socket` instead.

Comment: Good call Paul. This appears to be the exact issue i am seeing.